# CSS Typewriter animation: How to hide the second line text

Tags: css, animation

I've a problem using CSS typewriting animation :/
I'm making an animation of two lines of text but I want the second line of text to appear right after the first line's animation is finish. So that it looks like the animation continues to the second sentence seamlessly. Now although my h2's animation starts 3s afterwards but it appears at the beginning already (same time as h1). How to fix this?
Thanks! Here is the demo https://jsfiddle.net/zw9buowb/

```
.typewriter h1 {
   overflow: hidden; 
   border-right: .15em solid black; 
   white-space: nowrap; 
   margin: 0; 
   letter-spacing: 2px; 
   animation:
     typing 4s steps(30, end),
     blink-caret .75s step-end infinite;
}

.typewriter h2 {
   border-right: .15em solid black; 
   white-space: nowrap; 
   margin: 0; 
   letter-spacing: 2px;
   animation:
     typing 4s steps(30, end),
     blink-caret .75s step-end infinite;
   -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
}

.typewriter {
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Change the `h2` animation time to 7s....the delay is included in the *overall* time as I recall...but a demo would help.

Comment: Hi @Paulie_D Thanks for this but it doesn't seem to work. Here is the demo. :)